# Instance mismatch while plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot using seaborn

```
 data=pd.read_csv('MyCSV')
 data['Date']= pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
 start_date ='2016-04-18'
 end_date ='2016-04-21'

 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

 ax.plot(data.loc[start_date:end_date,'Date'].index, data.loc[start_date:end_date,"Price"], label='Price')


 ax.legend(loc='best')
 ax.set_ylabel('Price in $')
 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(my_year_month_fmt)
 plt.show()
```

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'`

However If i change my line to

```
 ax.plot(data['Date'].index, data["Price"], label='Price')
```

my graph is displayed but my dates get messed up. They all start from `1970-01-01`

My dataframe looks like this

```
   Date       Price   
0 2016-04-18  24.992023  
1 2016-04-19  24.859484  
2 2016-04-20  24.910643  
3 2016-04-21  24.640911
```

Comment: Are you using the latest matplotlib and pandas versions?

Answer (score -1):

```
data['Date']= pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data = data.set_index('Date')

start_date =datetime.strptime('2016-04-18', '%Y-%m-%d')
end_date =datetime.strptime('2016-04-21', '%Y-%m-%d')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

ax.plot(data.loc[start_date:end_date].index, data.loc[start_date:end_date, "Price"], label='Price')
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_ylabel('Price in $')
plt.show()
```

Note: `ax.plot(data.loc[start_date:end_date, "Price"], label='Price')` also works

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rohit can you please copy-paste the complete error

Comment: ``TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'``

Comment: I have updated the answer with the graph I got, please feel free to use the exact code to produce the graph, and see if it's throwing any error

Comment: can you update your code with the result of data.info() as well